# How to add cardview in layout xml in AndroidX

Tags: android, androidx

How to add cardview in layout xml in AndroidX

After upgraded to AndroidX

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp">
```

gives a error

> The following classes could not be found:
> - android.support.v7.widget.CardView (Fix Build Path, Edit XML, Create Class)

```
dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
    
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
```

but I don't know how to use CardView in xml under AndroidX

Thank you

Answer (score 114, accepted):

The class has changed to:

```
androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
```

If you want to use the old class names, you need to add `android:enableJetifier=true` to your `gradle.properties` and use the appcompat dependencies instead.

Answer (score 44):

I think the `Best Approach` should be like, understanding the problem statement first.

**Scenario:**

- Search for the library which Google Inc has changed for "AndroidX" and include in project

**Solution :**

Go to [Artifact Mappings](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate/artifact-mappings) page of Android Developer Site and Search for your desired library.
 
 [image] 
 
 Now go to [AndroidX Releases](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/versions/) page and check for the current version number 
 
 [image] 
 
 now go to `build.gradle[module.app]` add the library you want. (ie. CardView in my case) and press 
 `Sync Now` and necessary files will be added to your project by gradle.
 
 See the image below:
 
[image] 
 
Now in xml file you should get CardView or something you have just imported.

> NB: pictures included here are (the first two) taken from [Android Developer's Page](https://developer.android.com) which belongs to Google Inc and could be different depending on the time you see. See this post's posting time.

Comment: Excellent answer - well explained.

Comment: Well explained answer. Thanks

Answer (score 29):

You have 2 different options:

- [**Material Components MaterialCardView**](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/Card.md)

Just add:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0'
```

and in your xml you can use:

```
 <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
  ...>
```

- **Androidx CardView**

Just add:

```
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
```

and in your xml you can use:

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

**They are different:**

`MaterialCardView` **extends** `androidx.cardview.widget.CardView` and provides all of the features of CardView and

- add support for [**checking**](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/Card.md#making-a-card-checkable) and [**dragging**](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/Card.md#making-a-card-draggable)
- uses a `MaterialComponents` theme by default (it uses by deafult the style `Widget.MaterialComponents.CardView`)
- support the `ShapeAppearanceModel`
- adds attributes for customizing the stroke

Comment: I'm sorry but all reference links you posted is now invalid. Is your answer correct with current android version?

Comment: @nynohu Thanks for feedback.Links just fixed. And yes both work with current android version.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti thank you for this. The docs and codelabs seem to be horribly out of sync with 4.0.1 now. Makes it a nightmare to try and learn this stuff right now.

Answer (score 28):

For AndroidX, Add in gradle dependencies

`implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'`

Then in xml-layout use

`<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView`

Answer (score 13):

Add 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0' in gradle dependencies and modify xml accordingly.

Comment: Questioner have added 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0' into its dependencies as mentioned in the question.

Comment: But mentioning this thing help me lot, because I have forgotten

Comment: @JerryChong: But questioner did not change in xml file. There he mentioned 'android.support.v7.widget.CardView' in xml Tag.

Comment: i had tried most of the answers and this one worked for me

Answer (score 5):

Replace this line

from

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

to

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

This will work fine in **AndroidX**.

Comment: @ugali soft In the question descriptions, it already added "implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'". Therefore, it is not required to add this dependency again.

Comment: Yap Sure, For the first time it was confusing me i came direct to this answer without adding dependency.

Comment: @ugali soft Noted.

Answer (score 2):

`implementation com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0`

to

`implementation com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-alpha1`

it is download all design related class.
its work for Me

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in Android Studio 3.5.1. It worked for me:

```
def cardview_version = "1.0.0"
implementation "androidx.cardview:cardview:$cardview_version"


xmln: <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>....
```

Answer (score 0):

Changes in :
**1. build.gradle(:app)**

```
dependencies {
...
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0' 
....
}
```

**2. in xml section:**

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
...
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0' // must add this ``


               <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:id="@+id/game_id"
                android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
                app:cardBackgroundColor=""
                app:cardCornerRadius="15dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="130dp"
                        android:layout_height="170dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/gamess">

                    </ImageView>


                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="130dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/game"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Gamensjnjdhddgsgddgjsdjsdgjsgdjsgddgjsdjsdjg"
                        android:textColor="@color/white_color"
                        android:textSize="16dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold">

                    </TextView>
                </LinearLayout>

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

> `[![Blockquote][1]][1]`

Comment: implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
must add this