# How to use cardview in android

Tags: java, android, android-cardview

I try to do card view but i can't understand how to do a scrolling page with textview and a webview. Can someone show me the basic code of Card View.

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="432dp"
            android:layout_height="510dp"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

I want that  the page of my app that his a text view and a webview that the user can scroll. So I think that I can do that with cardview, but I can't understand the code of cardview that I saw on videos. How can I use this function with only a textview and a cardview?

I have looked some videos on CardView but I can't used their code for what I want to do. Me I have only  a text view and a webview that I want that the user can scroll. Would someone show some basic code of card view, and explain what it does?

Comment: please make your question more clear. add some codes or examples or UI to understand what you are actually trying to achieve

Comment: thanks i did it in the rush I'm sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the card view dependencies

```
   dependencies {
            implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
   }
```

Add the cardview in your layout

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/grey_300"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="5dp"
        card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="432dp"
            android:layout_height="510dp"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: when i compile i have this error The project 'info' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
Open Gradle wrapper file
                                                                                                                                but thanks for helping but i saw on video that there his a java code do we need to put it or not?

Comment: in what dependencies i need to put the compile code module app or Project info

Comment: Inside the app dependencies

Comment: cardview-v7:21.0.0-rc1 Really?? There are the  v28.0.0, the androidx version and the [material components version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53089633/how-to-add-cardview-in-layout-xml-in-androidx/57833454#57833454), but pls not a very very old RC.

Comment: thanks to help me i will let you know if i have any diffuclties

Comment: @Gabriele Not everyone using latest verion. By the way updated it

Comment: hello, i resolved the code i have the cardview that appear but when i scroll nothing change i think it's because i need the java code sorry to be annoying, but if someone can help me i would be happy.