# ERROR: Failed to resolve: cardview Affected Modules: app

Tags: android, android-studio, android-cardview, cardview

I want to use CardView in my project but it shows ERROR: Failed to resolve: cardview Affected Modules: app,Why?I checked dependencies and updated android studio but again it shows same error

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.dubsmash.volley:library:2.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0-alpha01'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.4.0-alpha01'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'

}
```

I can't add cardview. Layout is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="76dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/chewy"
        android:text="@string/title"
        android:textSize="36sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.525"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/57833454/2016562

Comment: Post the error, the code and the layout involved.

Answer (score 0):

Since AndroidX still has some weird bugs, you might solve it updating the android studio to newest version.

Also you can use `android.enablejetifier` to `false` in `gradle.properties` but you will have to use androidx libraries.

Answer (score -1):

just remove them

With just those 3 you can use both RecyclerView and CardView and a plus as well: ConstraintLayout

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha04'
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.1.0-alpha05'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
```

OR/AND

Add MaterialComponents:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha06'
```

Comment: Thanks but it shows ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha06.

Comment: @MexiCano Did you check the dependencies in the question? All the dependencies of the first block are already included in the build.gradle with updated versions. Also I can't understand why you are suggesting alpha releases when beta and stable versions are available.

Comment: I checked dependencies and updated android studio but again it shows same error.