# Why do I get a cardview error when I run my project?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-cardview

i get a source code in internet and i try to run it, but i get this error.((ERROR: Failed to resolve: cardview Affected Modules: app))how i can solve this error?
the following code is my build.gradle(madule:app), i try other version of library and update android studio even i try to delete every cardview in my project, but still have error.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.ecommerce"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1"
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.4.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.1.1'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.2.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.github.rey5137:material:1.2.5'
    //implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:29.1.1'
    //implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:29.1.1'
    implementation "androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0"
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
    implementation 'io.paperdb:paperdb:2.6'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:29.1.1'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.7.+'
    implementation 'com.cepheuen.elegant-number-button:lib:1.0.2'
    //implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0-alpha01'
}
```

Comment: I think maybe somewhere use Material Card view. So that the problem can be occur. You can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57833454/6652743) Also check [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53089654/6652743) for resolving this issue.

Comment: tnx for your answer,i checked my xml layout, its correct but still have error,does it could have other solution?

Comment: Post your layout and the full error.

Comment: @ GabrieleMariotti ,i post my full project in Github,I would greatly appreciate it if you help me.this is link of my project.[link](https://github.com/miladjavaheri/eCommerce)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First:**

You have to decide which dependencies of both **Support Library** or **AndroidX** you need in your application. You've added both Support Library and AndroidX dependencies to the project which is not correct.

Anyways, here is the right build.gradle after `Migrate to AndroidX` from `Refactor` menu:

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.4.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.3.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.1.1'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.2.2'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
implementation 'com.github.rey5137:material:1.2.5'
implementation "androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0"
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
implementation 'io.paperdb:paperdb:2.6'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.7.0'
implementation 'com.cepheuen.elegant-number-button:lib:1.0.2'
```

**Second:**

> ((ERROR: Failed to resolve: cardview Affected Modules: app)

This is because it cannot download the needed libraries from maven or any other repositories which is mostly caused by your IP limitations.

Comment: tnx for your attention, i use VPN but it seemed the problem remain unsolved, and we should consider other possibilities?

Comment: Have you tried updating your gradle to the latest version?: project level, build.gradle:  `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1'` Also make sure you didn't set the gradle to work in `offline mode`.

Comment: Thank you very much dear Mohsen, i update my gradle to 4.0.1 and its work.